# Raising ValidationError in a custom field's to_python() method breaks admin forms

Tags: django, django-admin, django-forms, django-models

I have a custom field called `CustomField` to wrap a class called `Example` like so:

```
from django import forms
from django.db import models
from . import Example

class CustomField(models.CharField):
    __metaclass__ = models.SubfieldBase

    def to_python(self, value):
        try:
            return Example(value)
        except Example.InvalidValueException:
            raise forms.ValidationError('bad value!')

    def get_prep_value(self, value):
        return unicode(value)

    def formfield(self, **kwargs):
        defaults = {'form_class': forms.CharField}
        defaults.update(kwargs)
        return super(CustomField, self).formfield(**defaults)
```

The problem is in admin forms: when `ValidationError` is raised in the `clean()` or `validate()` methods for a field, the error message is displayed neatly next to the respective input field in the form. However, when it's raised in the `to_python()` method like in my custom field, an invalid value breaks the form ungracefully and displays an error page with the traceback about `ValidationError`. How do I get my field to work correctly with the Django admin forms?

EDIT: Based on a suggestion below I tried:

```
class CustomFieldForm(forms.CharField):
    def validate(self, value):
        raise forms.ValidationError('test')
```

And changed the `formfield()` method to use the class like so:

```
    def formfield(self, **kwargs):
        defaults = {'form_class': CustomFieldForm}
        defaults.update(kwargs)
        return super(CustomField, self).formfield(**defaults)
```

Yet the `to_python()` method still gets called before the `CustomFieldForm.validate()` method and the `Example.InvalidValueException` raised in the former method in case of an invalid value breaks the admin form.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found the solution thanks to ojii pointing me in the right direction. Explanation is in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/howto/custom-model-fields/#modelforms-and-custom-fields) about `SubfieldBase`. In short, because I used `__metaclass__ = models.SubfieldBase`, I needed to subclass `forms.CharField` and raise the `ValidationError` from its `to_python()` method, and then use this in my field's `formfield()` method instead of plain `forms.CharField`.

Comment: Can you provide some more detail?  I'm not following what the final solution was.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should not raise a `forms.ValidationError` in a **model** field. Rather, in the field class returned in `formfield`, implement a `validate` method that accepts a `value` parameter. That method can raise form validation errors.

Comment: Your suggestion didn't work, I've updated the question with details. In short, the `to_python()` method still gets called first and breaks the form.

Comment: Also, the documentation on validation seems to contradict you: "The `to_python()` method on a `Field` is the first step in every validation. It coerces the value to correct datatype and raises `ValidationError` if that is not possible. This method accepts the raw value from the widget and returns the converted value. For example, a `FloatField` will turn the data into a Python float or raise a `ValidationError`."